# How to calculate the average of values present in all the table cells using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html-table

I want to get the average and max of the `<td>` values when a user clicks calculate button to the labels beside average and max

```
<html>
<table id="table" style="height:350px;margin-left:1em;width:700px;">
    <!--this is my table header-->
    <tr style="display:table-row">
        <th class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox"/></th>
        <th class="Name">NAME</th>
        <th class="Score">SCORE</th>
        <th class="Email">EMAIL</th>
        <th class="Empty"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <!--tabledata-->
        <td ><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td >Vijay Prakash</td>
        <td >34</td>
        <td >vijay@example.com</td>
        <td ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        //table data
        <td ><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td >Sashi Pagadala</td>
        <td >21</td>
        <td >sashi@example.com</td>
        <td ></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" id="btnCalculate" value="Calculate"/>
<label>Average:</label>
<label id="lblAverage"></label>
<label>Max:</label>
<label id="lblMax"></label>
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you try something ? What was the problem ?

Comment: Whenever a user clicks on calculate button the values in all td's should be taken and calculated and avg should get into lblaverage tag and maxvalue of all td's should get into lblmax tag....Can anyone help me?

Comment: I am not much familiar with jquery ..How to calculate those average and max values and display them..Please help me...

Comment: Then the problem is [to get familiar with jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery) ^^

Answer (score 1):

I added a class to your TD's containing numbers to make this easier.

HTML:

```
<td ><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td >Vijay Prakash</td>
<td class="number">34</td>
<td >vijay@gmail.com</td>
<td ></td>
```

jQuery

```
$("#btnCalculate").click(function() {
    var total = 0;
    var highCount = 0;

    $("table tr td.number").each(function() {
        total += Number($(this).text());
        if (highCount < $(this).text()) {
            highCount = $(this).text();
        }
    });

    $("#lblMax").text(highCount);
    $("#lblAverage").text(total / $("table tr td.number").length);
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Kjm6Z/1/

Comment: This looks good to me however it sounds as if he was asking for the highest score, not the total of all scores to be displayed in the lblMax... just add a var highScore = 0 and in the each loop check if the number is higher than highScore, if so set highScore to that number... ya know.

Comment: Thanx for the help...But I want the maximum of the values in the table not the total ...i,e I want the lblmax should be displayed as 34..not the sum of the cells

Comment: ahh, easy fix, give me a few minutes, basically, everything Ryan said

Comment: @BharatBhushan you could put some effort in finding the maximum of value in a numeric array, that's basic programming you shouldn't be begging for.

Comment: Guys will keep _am ain't begging_ and get away with it as long as they keep getting answers for low quality questions that have invalid HTML and show NO research effort at all.